# Phoenix: Use layout with templates of formats differents from html

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the default `app.html.eex` in `web/templates/layout/` and it works well with all my templates `*.html.eex`. I duplicated the `app.html.eex` file to `app.rss.eex` and I changed the content to the common RSS code to use in my `*.rss.eex` templates only the specific code, but it only renderize the `*.rss.eex` code and not to use the layout.

I tried to put in the pipeline `plug :put_layout, {Exampleapp.LayoutView, :app}` but it didn't work. Of course, I configured the accepts to use RSS with `plug :accepts, ["html", "rss"]` so that it can render `*.rss.eex` templates.

¿Is possible to use the layout with other formats?
¿How can I use the layout with `app.rss.eex` correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable layouts for your new format as well. You can do that by adding the [`:put_layout_formats`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#put_layout_formats/2) plug before `:put_layout`:

```
plug :put_layout_formats, ["html", "rss"]
plug :put_layout, ...
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!
is it in the Phoenix documentation? I searched it but I didn't find it.

Comment: Yes, that plug is documented here: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#put_layout_formats/2.

Comment: I see, I was triying to find a "Phoenix.Layout" doc, and searching in Google "phoenix rss layout" didn't work well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

option 1

```
render(conn, “index.html”, layout: {MyApp.LayoutView, “admin.html”})
```

option 2

```
conn
    |> put_layout({AdminView, "admin.html"})
    |> render :index
```

Comment: That could work for only render one view, but the question was focused to allow a new format layout, not only to one render, then answer of Dogbert just do that.